# Rotating a Color Image in Python Without Using Packages and Using Transformation Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, image-rotation

I am trying to create a method that rotates a color image in Python by 0, 90, 180, or 270 degrees. This is my code so far. As it stands, the output is a blank image. I also am trying to get the code to be as efficient as possible. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Image is a 3D array while rotate_angle is a int. The idea I was trying was to take all the (x,y) coordinates of pixels from the original image and multiply them with the transformation matrix (x_transformed, y_transformed). Then, the colors at (x_transformed, y_transformed) on the new image would just be the colors at (x,y) on the old image.

```
def rotate_image(image, rotate_angle):
    output_image = image
    # Convert degrees to radian
    angle = math.radians(rotate_angle)
    # For all values of height
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        # And all values of width
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            # Take the x and y coordinates of the existing points
            y = image.shape[0]-1
            x = image.shape[1]-1
            # Keep in mind rotation matrix is [(cos, sin), (-sin, cos)] [(x,y)]
            y_n = int(-x * math.sin(angle) + y * math.cos(angle))
            x_n = int(x * math.cos(angle) + y * math.sin(angle))
            # Rotating to where we are and then copying data from where we were
            output_image[y_n, x_n, :] = image[i, j, :]
    return output_image
```

Of course, if there is a more efficient way, I am also interested in knowing what it is. I know there are packages out there that can do what I am doing, but I wish to make the method myself and with the tools I have.

Comment: Everything that goes into the calculation of the `x_n` and `y_n` coordinates is *constant*, so you're setting the same output image pixel every time.  Shouldn't `i` and `j` be in there somewhere?  Also, you're destroying your input image as you go, because `output_image` is just another name for it - rather than a separate image.

Comment: I see the problem with x_n and y_n but I'm not sure if I agree with the other one. I make a copy of image when I run the first line do I not? That way image itself is still preserved.

Comment: No, you just assign another name to it.  *Nothing* in Python automatically makes a copy of anything, that always requires some specific action.